# I created a view programatically,but the background color is not getting changed from white

Tags: android

I created a view dynamically and set params using LayoutParams
after setting the background colour dynamically, it is still showing as white colour.

This is my code.

```
View line = new View(this);
        int margin = DisplayUtils.dpToPixel(5, this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, DisplayUtils.dpToPixel(1, this));
        params.setMargins(margin, 0, margin, 0);
        line.setLayoutParams(params);
        line.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
        ((ViewGroup) container).addView(line);
```

This is my container code

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.04"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Are you sure that line's parent is LinearLayout? Because if it isn't you have to declare LayoutParams for the right parent type

Comment: You are setting background coor to the line and not to background view. Try calling setBackgroundColor function on the container.

Comment: add some info about the container

Comment: I just looked , parent is linear layout only.

Comment: @Olayinka I have just added the container code

Comment: @BaluSKT Actually I need background for the view only . It will be displayed like a line but in the given colour instead of white.

Comment: could you share full xml code?

Comment: Please confirm, what will be the color of background and what will be the color of line?

Comment: Please upload complete layout file.

Comment: @BaluSKT color of view is code " #333333" and color of background is white

Comment: Thanks all solved it..sorry for delayed comment